file select browser can't access CIFS volume, apparmor or snap problem?
I'm running kubuntu 22.04 and I just installed a new program (czkawka) via snap that I'm using to find and remove duplicate images in my photo library.  My libraries are stored on some NAS volumes which I have mounted via CIFS.
As soon as I tried to run it, I ran into a problem.  When I try to add a search path using the file dialog, the file dialog won't let me browse past the mount point on my system in my /media/ directory.  It simply appears as a blank file icon instead of a directory in the file browser, and clicking on it does nothing.
I made sure to add the "removeable media" snap connection, as well as the udisks one.  It had no effect.  I then used snappy-debug to see what message pop up when I tried to access the mount point, and here's what I got:
Log: apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" profile="snap.czkawka.czkawka" pid=901436 comm="pool-czkawka_gu" laddr=192.168.1.69 lport=40884 faddr=192.168.1.4 fport=445 family="inet" sock_type="stream" protocol=6 requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send"

I started poking around with apparmor profiles but this is way out of my knowledge and I started getting messages I don't understand.
How do I solve this so I can access my NAS drives via CIFS in this application? I can access the shares fine in other applications.

Did you try the additional steps noted here: Is there a way for a snap application to access a network-mounted disk drive ?

@steeldriver: yes, that's what I was referring to when I mentioned that I had made sure that the snap had the "removeable_media" snap connection.  I did not try the devmode option.  But I suspect it's apparmor that's blocking me, based on the log message?
